# При обновлении БД (MSSQL) возникает ошибка "There is already an object named 'Weapons' in the database."

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

При запуске команды update-database происходит ошибка:

> There is already an object named 'Weapons' in the database.

Есть несколько моделей EF Core (упрощенная структура):

```
abstract class Weapon {
   public int    Id   { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Axe : Weapon {
}

class Sword : Weapon {
}

class GameDbContext : DbContext {
    public DbSet<Weapon>   Weapons   { get; set; }

    public GameDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options){
        this.Database.EnsureCreated();
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
         base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

         this.SetModelsConfigurations(modelBuilder);

         modelBuilder.Entity<Axe>  ().HasBaseType<Weapon>();
         modelBuilder.Entity<Sword>().HasBaseType<Weapon>();
    }
}
```

Команда - "add-migration Init" для приведенных моделей выполняется нормально, без ошибок. Но при запуске команды update-database происходит ошибка:

> There is already an object named 'Weapons' in the database.

Почему происходит данная ошибка? Какие настройки БД нужно выполнить/удалить/добавить, что бы заставить код работать?

Comment: вы не показываете ни схему БД, и код миграции, и спрашиваете о каких то проблемах наката миграции на схему.

Comment: @tym32167 Спасибо за отклик на вопрос. Мне уже помогли на английской версии сайта. Судя по всему вся проблема была в методе this.Database.EnsureCreated(); Если я правильно понял смысл оставленного там комментария, то в результате использования данного метода с одновременным вызовом команд add-migration и update-database из консоли, EF Core пытался создать БД дважды, что по смыслу соответствует выдаваемой им ошибке. После того как я удалил метод, все заработало.

Comment: @AK я уже читал много раз) Но спасибо за помощь!

Comment: [Похоже на правду](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.infrastructure.databasefacade.ensurecreated?view=efcore-2.1) `Note that this API does not use migrations to create the database. In addition, the database that is created cannot be later updated using migrations. If you are targeting a relational database and using migrations, you can use the DbContext.Database.Migrate() method to ensure the database is created and all migrations are applied.`

Comment: @tym32167 Прочитал, спасибо. Кажется теперь все стало на своим места.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно [документации DatabaseFacade.EnsureCreated](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.infrastructure.databasefacade.ensurecreated?view=efcore-2.1)

> Note that this API does not use migrations to create the database. In addition, the database that is created cannot be later updated using migrations. If you are targeting a relational database and using migrations, you can use the DbContext.Database.Migrate() method to ensure the database is created and all migrations are applied.

Вольный перевод

> Данное API не использует миграции для создания БД. Кроме того, созданная таким образом БД уже не может быть обновлена при помощи миграций. Если вам нужна реляционная БД и вы используете миграции, вы можете использовать `DbContext.Database.Migrate()` для того чтобы убедиться, что БД создана и все необходимые миграции применены.