# Как удалить все таблицы через Entity framework, при этом не перечисляя наименования таблиц (или сущностей)?

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core, nunit

У меня есть следующий код юнит-теста.

```
public class NewTest
{
    private ApplicationContext context;
    private IMigrator migrator;

    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        IConfiguration configuration =
            new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.Tests.json", false).Build();

        context = new ApplicationContext(configuration);
        migrator = context.GetService<IMigrator>();
        migrator.Migrate();

    }

    [Test]
    public void Can_Create_Workspace()
    {
        // как то удалить абсолютно все таблицы из тестовой базы

        // выполнить миграции
        migrator.Migrate();

        // далее код теста
    }
}
```

Для моих юнит-тестов я планирую развернуть в докере отдельную базу. В методе `Setup` происходит настройка: создается подключение к базе, выполняются миграции. Далее план такой. В каждом тесте мне хотелось бы удалить все таблицы из базы, как будто бы я еще не проводил ни одной миграции и у меня пустая база. Далее, в каждом тесте я выполняю миграции и работаю с базой. То есть я проверяю одновременно, что у меня работает и моя бизнес-логика, и репозитории (хранение).

Примерно так организованы юнит-тесты в php фреймворке Laravel. Я нахожу это удобным и хотел бы повторить. 
Проблема только в том, что я не нашел, как удалить абсолютно все таблицы из базы (включая таблицу списка миграций `__EFMigrationsHistory`). Все найденные мною способы основаны на перечислении существующих таблиц в прямом SQL запросе. Это создает ограничения: привязку к конкретной СУБД (диалект SQL) и привязку к конкретному количеству таблиц (если добавится еще одна, то придется править все тесты). Также я находил решения, где люди предлагают удалять сущности через api Entity. Но тогда останется `__EFMigrationsHistory` и в следующем тесте миграции не пройдут.

Было бы здорово, если было бы что-то типа

```
`context.DropAllTables()`
```

Заранее благодарен за любую помощь!

Comment: 1) Попробуйте дропнуть всю БД перед тестом. 2) `если добавится еще одна, то придется править все тесты` используйте один метод для всех тестов

Comment: Пока для себя я решил этот вопрос так `private void PrepareDbForTest()
        {
            // удалить все таблицы 
            context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("DROP SCHEMA public CASCADE;");
            context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("CREATE SCHEMA public;");
            // выполнить миграции
            migrator.Migrate();
        }`
Но тут я привязываюсь к конкретному диалекту SQL, как я и писал в своем вопросе, что для меня является проблемой. Я вызываю этот метод перед каждым тестом.

Comment: `context.Database.Delete()`?

Comment: Есть `EnsureDeleted()`, сейчас попробую, вдруг сработает.

Comment: `EnsureDeleted` действительно удаляет базу. В пару с ним пытаюсь использовать `EnsureCreated` чтобы снова создать базу. И он создает. Почему-то со всеми таблицами, кроме `__EFMigrationsHistory`, дальше, как следствие, миграции не проходят.

Comment: `EnsureCreated` не нужен. оказалось, что для моей задачи можно использовать только `context.Database.EnsureDeleted(); migrator.Migrate();`. Два метода. И все работает.

Comment: используйте [`DbContext.Database.Migrate()`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/908821/179763)